# Correct semantic for listing content in (X)HTML

Tags: html, xhtml, html-lists, semantics, markup

I would like to know what is the correct way (semantically) to build a page for listing something like users, products, articles, etc.

What is semantically correct? Listing items using the `ul/ol` tags or `div` tags?

The purpose of the page is to list something. So, I guess `ul/ol` should be used. On the other side, these lists aren't navigational menus or somekind of list of related items.

So, what's your opinion about this?

Answer (score 2):

If it is a list then use the 'ul'/'ol' tags. If it is tabular data, use a 'table'.

Comment: Yes it is a list. Let me show you some examples:

- Regular wordpress blog: http://hugoduraes.com/
Div tags are being used to list articles

- Restaurants list: http://www.igogo.pt/restaurantes/
ul/ol tags are being used to list restaurants

What is more correct to list these kind of contents?

Answer (score 1):

> The purpose of the page is to list something.

As mentioned by you, you are listing something so use `ul` and `ol` tags :)

Comment: Yes it is a list. Let me show you some examples: - Regular wordpress blog: hugoduraes.com Div tags are being used to list articles - Restaurants list: igogo.pt/restaurantes ul/ol tags are being used to list restaurants What is more correct to list these kind of contents?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely list `ul` and `ol` tags.

Though, if you do care about semantics in web documents, please consider using HTML5 (now renamed only to HTML) semantic features in order to replace non-semantic `div` tags in the case you are using any. You can find a really good introduction at http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/semantics.html

Comment: He does not need HTML5 to display some lists in a semantically correct way. Semantics do not start at HTML5.

Comment: I haven't told him he needs HTML5 to display some list in a semantically correct way. Nevertheless, I've modified my answer just to make its meaning more clear.